# Como Borrar registros diarios y mantener el ultimo del mes

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una tabla que se va llenado diariamente con información de un TXT, necesito hacer que me deje los ultimos de cada mes y el cargado diario sea eliminado por el dia siguiente es decir si hoy se cargo día 01/08 el dia de mañana deberia borrarlo y cargar 02/08 pero siempre respetando que los meses anteriores el ultimo txt de cada mes debe quedar para ir formando historia, me podrían ayudar

los identifico por [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade lo que hayas intentado por favor

Comment: Bienvenide Genesis Josefina a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Como ya te comentaron, añade lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora, y que problemas has tenido, agrega también la estructura de la tabla, todo como texto no como imagen.

Comment: No puedo ver tu imagen, seria mejor que pegues el script de tu tabla, si usas datetime en tu campo, entonces sera mas facil, sigue este link https://bloginspanish.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/funciones-de-fecha-utiles-en-sql-server/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

Como no estás manejando fechas sino números que muestran fecha, entonces es múy fácil hacer el borrado de días anteriores mientras que dejas el último día del mes anterior. Ten en cuenta que si llega a fallar un día, puedes terminar con conjuntos de datos de múltiples días del mismo mes porque solo valida el día anterior.

```
--Usamos CONVERT para cambiar la fecha a texto y la resta para cambiar el texto a entero.
DELETE FROM TuTabla 
WHERE fecha_proceso = CONVERT( char(8), GETDATE(), 112) - 1;
```

Cuando sea el primer día del mes, tratará de borrar el día cero de ese mes que no existe. Cuando sea cualquier otro día del mes, borrará el día anterior.